# How Do I Rotate Selected Curve Points From Specific Axis?

Tags: bezier-curves

I feel like this is easy but I'm stumped:

How do I rotate these selected points on my curve, from Point A, where Point A is the anchor point and the other two points sweep out accordingly as I rotate?

I have the origin set to the selected point, as well as the 3D Cursor, however, using either of those for the Transform Orientation doesn't work. The selected points rotate around the center of the selection, and not around Point A.

What am I missing here?  First pic is what I want, second pic is what I get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean you [do this](https://i.imgur.com/6PmNbqh.mp4) (select *Active Element* as the *Transform Pivot Point* and make sure point A is the active) and it still rotates around B? Your gizmo should show up on the active element in the first place, which it doesn't in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to move the origin, just set the 3D cursor where you want to pivot (Shift S > cursor to selected) and set the 3D cursor as pivot point. Then select what you want to rotate and rotate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. I mistakenly thought setting the Transform Orientation was the method. Totally forgot about the pivot point. Cheers.